# FoxPro How To Correctly Update a Variable Based On Table Values

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am writing a FoxPro program which is accessing multiple tables and updating some of their values after running values through equations.  I am trying to store the result of an equation in a variable (set) as such:

```
b = table1.base
ser = table2.load*b
```

Despite not showing some of the surrounding code, this should return a positive numeric value, however it just returns 0.0. What I have noticed is that if I print this quantity,

```
?table2.load*b
```

it indeed prints the correct result. How come this correct result is not being stored in the variable ser ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: That one also looks as if a Minimal, Reproducible Example would help :) Just two `Create Cursor` statements and `Insert Into` lines to show the data types and values

Comment: CREATE CURSOR table1 (base Int)
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (15)
CREATE CURSOR table2 (load Int)
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (6)

LOCAL b, ser
b = table1.base
ser = table2.load * m.b && the m. tells FoxPro that b is a variable as opposed to an alias row/column

? ser && prints 90

Comment: IOW, not using the `m.` prefix would be a possible cause of the symptom you described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code would reproduce your observation, and the solution to cure the spooky symptom would be FoxPro's peculiar `m.` prefix which clarifies that a certain name expression is a variable as opposed to an (alias.)column.
Don't hesitate to post back if your scenario / reason / repro is somehow different

```
CLEAR 
CREATE CURSOR table1 (base Int)
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (15)
CREATE CURSOR table2 (load Int)
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (6)

LOCAL b, ser
b = table1.base

CREATE CURSOR SomethingElse(b Int Null)
INSERT INTO somethingElse VALUES (0)
ser = table2.load * b
? ser && prints 0

ser = table2.load * m.b && the m. tells FoxPro that b is a variable as opposed to an alias row/column

? m.ser && prints 90
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the swift response. That indeed seemed to fix my problem. It also seemed like adding PUBLIC b, ser  also fixed that problem. Either way, thanks. Now onto my next question ! haha

Comment: The scoping topic, `Public` vs `Local` vs undeclared in Vfp is also worth a web search -- simplified: the `Local` scope declaration is the best protection level against unintentional overwriting, undeclared variables is the worst

Comment: If I could ask you another quick question in this comment that would be much appreciated. How can I sum certain values in a table column which satisfy a condition. I am just slightly unsure about the syntax. I am trying something like: sum(table1.val) where table1.val = table2.val .

Comment: SO would suggest to create a new Question for a new topic, and I would too because it could possibly help others having a similar one, and also the code examples for the Sum alternatives would be too much for a small comment box

Comment: It would be twice as unreadable as this :) CREATE CURSOR test (id Int, amount N(15,2))
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 15.45)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 8)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 9)
SUM amount FOR id = 1 TO result
? m.result

Answer (score 1):

First, I wouldn't use "set" as a variable name because it's a reserved word.

How are you checking the value of the result? Try looking with the Debugger. It should be in the Locals window.

Tamar